# Generate CSR with SHA2 using DigiCert tool

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-cloud-services, sha2

I'm trying to generate CSR for an Azure Cloud Service, but I need it to have a SHA2 signature algorithm.

So far I used DigiCert for windows to create these CSRs, but they only provide SHA1 algorithm.
How can I manage to do so? Am I missing something?

- Already saw [that link](https://www.digicert.com/transitioning-to-sha-2.htm) - not helpful (they tell us to use the DigiCert tool but it creates SHA1..)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a SHA-2 CSR in order to get a certificate signed with a SHA-2 signature algorithm.

DigiCert will default to signing your certificate with SHA-2 regardless of what is included in the CSR.